# Can I bulk delete documents without specifying a routing key?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `python-elasticsearch` (https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to bulk insert documents on an ES cluster with multiple shards. I'm using a `routing` during the insertion, but I don't have access to that key on deletion

Is there a way to hit all shards? Something like `routing=*`. If I don't specify a routing key ES is not able to find the document

This

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1", "routing": "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } } // Fails because routing is missing
```

gives me

```
{
  "took" : 1334,
  "errors" : false,
  "items" : [
    {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "created",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 0,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 201
      }
    },
    {
      "delete" : {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_version" : 1,
        "result" : "not_found",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 2,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 0,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 404
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: May be you could try deleting by query using "Delete by query API" if you have a pattern. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I managed to make it work with `delete_by_query`. That's weird that `delete_by_query` is hiting all shards if you're not specifying `routing` but `bulk delete` doesn't

Comment: Glad it helped.